# Ruby on rails app using omniauth-twitter is not working on heroku "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-oauth, omniauth, omniauth-twitter

I built an app that connects to twitter through oAuth and prints out your followers. I have been trying to push it to heroku and everytime I try to login to twitter through:

`<li><%= link_to 'Twitter', '/auth/twitter' %></li>`

I get the **"We're sorry, but something went wrong."** error.

Here are my heroku logs:

```
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330165+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-twitter-1.4.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:61:in `request_phase'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330167+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `request_call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330169+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:188:in `call!'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330171+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330173+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:64:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330176+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330178+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330180+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330182+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330185+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330187+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330189+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330191+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330193+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330195+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330197+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330200+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330202+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330204+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330206+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330208+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330210+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330212+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330214+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330216+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330218+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330220+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330228+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330231+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330233+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330235+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330237+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330239+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330241+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330243+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330245+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330247+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.330250+00:00 app[web.1]: [baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2019-11-29T04:35:25.332408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/twitter" host=demoapptwitterfollow.herokuapp.com request_id=baa3d054-cebe-4b91-abbe-36089431d1e7 fwd="190.186.200.42" dyno=web.1 connect=15ms service=161ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2019-11-29T04:37:39.224732+00:00 heroku[run.6110]: State changed from up to complete
2019-11-29T04:37:39.208264+00:00 heroku[run.6110]: Process exited with status 0
2019-11-29T04:37:52.904127+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.904025 #4]  INFO -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b] Started GET "/" for 190.186.200.42 at 2019-11-29 04:37:52 +0000
2019-11-29T04:37:52.905237+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.905167 #4]  INFO -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b] Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2019-11-29T04:37:52.912529+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.912435 #4] DEBUG -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b]   UserFollower Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "user_followers".* FROM "user_followers" WHERE "user_followers"."user_id" IS NULL
2019-11-29T04:37:52.914210+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.914104 #4] DEBUG -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b]   Follower Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "followers".* FROM "followers" WHERE 1=0
2019-11-29T04:37:52.914913+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.914838 #4]  INFO -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b]   Rendering pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2019-11-29T04:37:52.916628+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.916516 #4] DEBUG -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b]   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-11-29T04:37:52.917028+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.916936 #4]  INFO -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b]   Rendered pages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
2019-11-29T04:37:52.918945+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.918850 #4] DEBUG -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b]   CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
2019-11-29T04:37:52.919223+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.919130 #4]  INFO -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b]   Rendered shared/_nav.html.erb (1.2ms)
2019-11-29T04:37:52.919689+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:52.919562 #4]  INFO -- : [cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b] Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
2019-11-29T04:37:52.925723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=demoapptwitterfollow.herokuapp.com request_id=cb818993-abc6-4a86-96e6-7e8ed265671b fwd="190.186.200.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=27ms status=200 bytes=2894 protocol=https
2019-11-29T04:37:53.992084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=demoapptwitterfollow.herokuapp.com request_id=47ed7904-80d4-42ea-97b0-9867d5a4c630 fwd="190.186.200.42" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2019-11-29T04:37:59.829936+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:59.829791 #4]  INFO -- : [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] Started GET "/auth/twitter" for 190.186.200.42 at 2019-11-29 04:37:59 +0000
2019-11-29T04:37:59.830430+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-11-29T04:37:59.830356 #4]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Request phase initiated.
2019-11-29T04:38:00.011908+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-11-29T04:38:00.011761 #4] FATAL -- : [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf]
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012055+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-11-29T04:38:00.011968 #4] FATAL -- : [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] OAuth::Unauthorized (403 Forbidden):
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012165+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-11-29T04:38:00.012083 #4] FATAL -- : [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf]
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012339+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-11-29T04:38:00.012228 #4] FATAL -- : [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth-0.5.4/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:236:in `token_request'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012342+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth-0.5.4/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:155:in `get_request_token'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012345+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-oauth-1.1.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:28:in `request_phase'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012347+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-twitter-1.4.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/twitter.rb:61:in `request_phase'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012349+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:226:in `request_call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012351+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:188:in `call!'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012353+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012355+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.9.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:64:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012357+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012360+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012362+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012364+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012366+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012368+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012370+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012372+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012374+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012377+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012379+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012381+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012383+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012385+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012387+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012389+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012391+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012393+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012395+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012397+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012399+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012401+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012408+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012410+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012412+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012414+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012417+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012419+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012421+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012423+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012425+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012427+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.012429+00:00 app[web.1]: [9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2019-11-29T04:38:00.017843+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/auth/twitter" host=demoapptwitterfollow.herokuapp.com request_id=9d52b57c-2685-4409-81f4-600d126195cf fwd="190.186.200.42" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=191ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
```

What Im getting is that there is a  **OAuth::Unauthorized (403 Forbidden)** error.

I have added my keys and everything through the heroku console but the problem persists.

How can I fix this in heroku?

Comment: Can you share what you specified as the callback URL ? It should look something like this `http://<heroku_url>/auth/twitter/callback`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback url should be like this:

https://your_domain.herokuapp.com/users/auth/twitter/callback.

In twitter app settings mention as this.

Comment: Thank you!! 

I got it with **https://**<heroku_url>/auth/twitter :)